# Applying topology definitions on a particular example

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am an undergraduate student and I want to prepare myself for the final exams in real-analysis. I met this problem, but I'm not sure how it should be solved. Could you please help me?
Let $X$=$[0, \infty)$ and $T$={$\emptyset$, $X$}$\cup${$[0,a)$: $a>0$}.
How can I prove that $T$ is a topology on $X$? How can I check whether $(X,T)$ is compact and connected? How can I find the closure and interior of {$0$}?

Comment: Use the definitions

Comment: I know that $T$ is a topology if $\emptyset$,$X$ are in $T$ and also $T$ is closed under arbitrary unions and under finite intersections...But I don't know how to apply these on this exercise...

Comment: What does an arbitrary union or finite intersection of members of this $T$ look like?

Comment: I'm not sure...

Comment: a finite intersection of $\{[0,a_i)|i\in\{1,2,...,n\}\}$ will be $[0,\min\limits_{i\in\{1,2,...,n\}} a_i)$, and you also have to consider that one of the sets you are taking the intersection of could be $\emptyset$, and you should include the intersection of no sets

Comment: $(X,T)$ is not compact because $\{[0,n)|n\in\mathbb N\}$ is an open cover of $X$ without a finite subcover

Comment: Oh, I think I understand now... So, an arbitrary union will be the same interval but with maximum instead of minimum?

Comment: Yes, and you also have to consider that one of the sets you are taking the union of could be $X$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first axiom of a topology is clear on inspection: $\emptyset$ and $X$ are explicitly mentioned as members of $\mathcal{T}$.

To see that the intersection of two members from $\mathcal{T}$ is in $\mathcal{T}$ (which is sufficient for the second axiom), let $O_1, O_2 \in \mathcal{T}$ be arbitrary, and we can assume WLOG that $O_1, O_2$ are both not equal to $\emptyset$ or $X$ (as this would trivialise the intersection to either $\emptyset$ or one of the $O_i$, already in $\mathcal{T}$). So $O_1 = [0,a_1)$ for some $a_1 >0$ and $O_2 = [0,a_2)$ for some $a_2 >0$. It is clear that defining $a:= \min(a_1,a_2)$ we have that $O_1 \cap O_2 = [0,a) \in \mathcal{T}$ and so we are done.

For the final axiom, let $O_i, i \in I$ be a family of sets from $\mathcal{T}$. We want to show that $O:= \bigcup_i O_i$ is in $\mathcal{T}$ as well. First note that we can disregard any $O_i$ that are equal to $\emptyset$ as they have no effect on the union, and if any $O_i = X$, $O=X$ too and we'd be done already. So WLOG $O_i  =[0, a_i)$ for some $a_i > 0$ (the only other form of set in $\mathcal{T}$).
We define $a := \sup \{a_i: i \in I\}$ (this could be $\infty$ too, or some finite number $>0$.) I claim that $O = [0,a) \in \mathcal{T}$ in either case:

> If $x \in [0,a)$ then $x < a$, and $x$ cannot be an upper bound for $\{a_i: i \in I\}$, or it would be a strictly smaller upper bound for that set than its supremum $a$ which cannot be. So some $a_i$ exists such that $x < a_i$, and so $x \in [0,a_i)=O_i$ so $x \in O$. OTOH, if $x \in O$, we have that $x \in O_i$ for some $i$ and then $x < a_i \le a$, and so $x \in [0,a)$. This double inclusion shows the equality of sets.

So the union $O$ is in $\mathcal{T}$ and so we have a topology. QED.

---

$\{0\}$ has empty interior (no open set exept $\emptyset$ is a subset of it) and has closure $X$ (all open sets that are non-empty contain $0$, so intersect $\{0\}$.

I hope this solution gives you a model to follow for your other exercises.

Comment: Thank you very much, it is very helpful and I understood the reasoning!

Comment: @Beni you’re welcome!