# How to prove that a set is a topology

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let  $T=\{\emptyset\}\cup\{\{m \in \mathbb{N} : m \geq n\}: n \in \mathbb{N}\}$, where $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,...\}$.

How can I prove that $T$ is a topology on $N$?

How can I check whether $(N,T)$ is compact and connected?

How can I find the closure and interior of $\{1\}$?

Comment: Do you know the definitions of all these concepts? If so, the answer to your question is simple: check if they are true or not.

Comment: Similar to your [other question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3742316/how-to-prove-that-some-sets-are-topologies)

Comment: So you know nothing about topology?

Comment: I know the three conditions that a set has to accomplish in order to be a topology...$\emptyset$ is obviously in $T$, but how about $X$? Then, an arbitrary union will be {$\emptyset$} $\cup$$N$? And also, a finite intersection will be {$\emptyset$}$\cup${$1$}? How can I prove that these sets are in $T$?

Comment: Moreover, I know that $int$({$1$})=$\emptyset$, but I can't justify why...And $cl$({$1$})={$\emptyset$}$\cup${2,3,4,...} but I can't justify why again...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will write $A_n := \{m \in \mathbb{N} : m \geq n\}$.

First thing to note is you didn't specify that $X$ was in your topology, so you need to add that in. Other than that everything is fine.

You need it to be closed under arbitrary unions. If $\{n_i\}$ is any set of natural numbers, what is $\bigcup A_{n_i}$? Try experimenting with some small sets of you're unsure. Similarly what is $\bigcap A_{n_i}$? (Your topology is actually closed under arbitrary intersections, but probably easier to just think of the finite case.)

For your last question. The interior is defined as the union of all open sets contained in your set. Which open sets are contained in $\{1\}$?

Similarly the closure is the intersection of all closed sets containing $\{1\}$. The closed sets are just the complements of the open sets. Which of them contain 1?

Edit: for your question about compactness and connectedness, in both cases think of which open sets contain 0.

Comment: For this notation, $A_n$ will always be the same, no matter of what values will take $n$...

Comment: I had a typo, it was meant to say m>n. I fixed it now.

Comment: I think that $\cup$$A_n$=$N$ and $\cap$$A_n$=$\{n\}$. Then, $cl$($\{1\}$)=$\{2,3,...\}$ and $int$($\{1\}$)=$\emptyset$, because there is no closed set containing {$1$}?

Comment: My problem is that I don't understand how this set $T$ looks like...Is it {$\emptyset$}$\cap${1,2,3,...}$\cap${2,3,4,...}$\cap${3,4,5,...}...{n}?

Comment: $T = \{ \emptyset, \{1, 2, 3, ...\}, \{2, 3, 4, ...\}, ...\}

Comment: For checking whether $(X,T)$ is a T1 space, it is ok to say that $X$=$\{0\}$$\cup$$(0,\infty)$, so $X$ is an open set. Thus, for every neighborhood of a number y, we can find a number x belonging to that neighborhood as well, so it is not a T1 space